# Filtering of groups in dataframes

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I try to filter out groups using pandas, I have tried the groupby but can't find out how to filter whole groups out with criteria from the DF. Below is a print of my dataframe. I want to group the users (1-4) and then filter based on whether they have a primary or not, then only show the users who do not have a primary account. Anyone got an idea for this?

So far my code looks like

```
df=pd.read_csv("accounts_test.csv")

grouped = df.groupby('User')
```

Dataframe:

```
       User primary   account_type
0      1     NaN  current_acc
1      1     yes      savings
2      1     NaN       invest
3      2     NaN  current_acc
4      2     NaN       invest
5      2     NaN      savings
6      3     NaN      savings
7      3     yes  current_acc
8      3     NaN       invest
9      4     NaN      savings
10     4     NaN       invest
11     4     NaN  current_acc
```

Wanted output after filtering:

```
       User primary   account_type

3      2     NaN  current_acc
4      2     NaN       invest
5      2     NaN      savings

9      4     NaN      savings
10     4     NaN       invest
11     4     NaN  current_acc
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can try via `groupby()`+`filter()`:

```
df.groupby('User').filter(lambda x:x['primary'].ne('yes').all())
```

OR

via use `groupby()`+`transform()` as a mask and then pass it to `df`:

```
df[df.groupby('User')['primary'].transform(lambda x:x.ne('yes').all())]
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way using only fast optimized vectorized operation (without using lambda function):

Use [`.loc`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) + [`.groupby()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) + [`.transform()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.transform.html) on [`'all'`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.all.html):

```
df.loc[df['primary'].ne('yes').groupby(df['User']).transform('all')]
```

or, if your `NaN` is null value equivalent to `np.nan`, you can also use:

```
df.loc[df['primary'].isna().groupby(df['User']).transform('all')]
```

**Result:**

```
    User primary account_type
3      2     NaN  current_acc
4      2     NaN       invest
5      2     NaN      savings
9      4     NaN      savings
10     4     NaN       invest
11     4     NaN  current_acc
```